# Merging all materials

Tags: texturing

I have a project where several materials use the same texture.
I would like to have only a single material.

I have uploaded my project here:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45922

Could anybody please tell me how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Your materials are not all the same here. "rubber" does not have the same specular value. But except that, if you only keep the material named "body and teeth", that should make the job. Use the "minus" sign on the right of the materials list to delete each.

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend file uploads. It is more permanent that pasteall.